# Pass some data from fetch array to int in JSON.Stringify

Tags: json, reactjs, jwt

i try to POST data to server. my problem is, i get error '422 (Unprocessable Entity)' because the data all in string so i need convert some data to int.
How to convert some of data to int from array before bind to other parameters?
i need convert some of data which invono & lotno to int.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   isLoaded: false,
   alldata: [],
   singledata: {
     invono: "",
     invodate: "",
     lotno: "",
     buildup: "",
     custid: "",
   },
 };


createInvoice() {
fetch("http://xxx:8081/invoice", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(this.state.singledata),

  //JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.singledata)),
 // JSON.stringify({this.state.singledata : parseInt($({this.state.singledata.invono}).val(),10)})
}).then(
  this.setState({
    singledata: {
      invono: "",
      invodate: "",
      lotno: "",
      buildup: "",
      custid: "",
    },
  })
);
}
```

handler for user input.

```
handleChange(event) {
var invono = this.state.singledata.invono;
var invodate = this.state.singledata.invodate;
var lotno = this.state.singledata.lotno;
var buildup = this.state.singledata.buildup;
var custid = this.state.singledata.custid;
if (event.target.name == "invono") invono = event.target.value;
else if (event.target.name == "invodate") invodate = event.target.value;
else if (event.target.name == "lotno") lotno = event.target.value;
else if (event.target.name == "buildup") buildup = event.target.value;
else if (event.target.name == "custid") custid = event.target.value;

this.setState({
  singledata: {
    invono: invono,
    invodate: invodate,
    lotno: lotno,
    buildup: buildup,
    custid: custid,
  },
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` for number fields.

```
handleChange(event) {
  const fieldname = event.target.name;
  // put in the names of the fields that need to be converted to integers into
  // the array below
  const convertToInts = ["invono", "lotno"];
  const value = convertToInts.includes(fieldname) ? parseInt(event.target.value, 10) : event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    singledata: {
      ...this.state.singledata,
      [fieldname]: value,
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: why do we have to do this to use `int`? isn't it stupid to make it this difficult? who are these people creating these programming languages...they may need to start doing IQ test for contributors